# How to populate a DropDownListBox with the values of an Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I need to populate the DropDownListBox with an array but i am having some problems.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim arrEmployeeID() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    Dim x As Integer

        For x = LBound(arrEmployeeID) To UBound(arrEmployeeID)
            ddlEmployeeID.Items.Add(arrEmployeeID(x))
        Next
End Sub
```

That is what I currently have. However, every time I select an item from the DropDownListBox, it adds 9 more values.

Here is an example of what is shown in the dropdownlistbox when I select an item for the first time.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The values in the array will keep on adding on each time I select one.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: do you have any code in your DropDownListBox selection event?

Comment: no it's in the form load event

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in the form load event, does it execute when you select an item?

Comment: no it does not execute the code

Comment: if the form load event is the only code that adds values, something is executing it. Are you doing something else that would cause the form load event to fire? Also you can add `ddlEmployeeID.Items.Clear` in that load event to clear all items before you load anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DataSource + DataBind methods, no need to add everything one per one

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim arrEmployeeID() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        'no postback, so set the datasource, and bind it'
        DropDownList1.DataSource = arrEmployeeID
        DropDownList1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

following could help friend.
The following code is for the combobox.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim arrEmployeeID() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    cboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList 'It allows only to use the drop down list values or do not allow to edit the values.
    cboBox.DataSource = arrEmployeeID
End Sub
```

The following code is for the ListBox

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim arrEmployeeID() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    'Make sure that the listbox is empty 
    lstBox.Items.Clear()

    For i = 0 To arrEmployeeID.Length - 1
        lstBox.Items.Add(arrEmployeeID(i.ToString))
   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are calling the Page_Load method from elsewhere?

KnockKnocks answer isnt bad, but you might also use a different for each structure

```
For i = 0 To arrEmployeeID.Length - 1
    lstBox.Items.Add(arrEmployeeID(i.ToString))
Next
```

Instead of that, I suggest this, because its a bit easier to read

```
For Each item As Integer In arrEmployeeID
 lstBox.Items.Add(arrEmployeeID(i.ToString))
Next
```